# Try to load the images before it can be laid out in pinInterest layout

Tags: jquery

```
    <div id="popup-freewall" class="freewall">
        <g:each in="${similarImages}" var="other">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="grid-tile">
                    <a class="overlay fancybox" href="/more/${other.id}">
                   <img src="${other.referralImage}" width="100%" />
                    </a>

                </div>

                <div class="info">
                    <p>${other.description}</p>
                </div><!--end detail-container-->
            </div>
        </g:each>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  // imagesLoaded('#popup-freewall', function(){
  var wall = new freewall("#popup-freewall");

  var $imgs = $('.grid-tile img').length;

  $imgs.on('load', function(){
    -- $imgs;
    if(!$imgs){
     $imgs.show();
      wall.fitWidth();
  }
  }).filter(function(){
    return this.complete;
  }).trigger('load');


 });



  wall.reset({
    selector: '.grid-container',
    animate: false,
    cellW: 200,
    cellH: 'auto',
    fixSize: 1,
    gutterX: 20,
    gutterY: 20,
    onResize: function() {
      wall.fitWidth();
      wall.refresh();
    },
  });

  wall.fitWidth();
  // });
});
</script>
```

Right now, the commented lines are what I copied from freewall.js demo, but it doesn't work too well for my case. 
Should be able to store all images in array then check if they are counted till no more left, then display all images and freewall will re-fit them in the layout.

I saw that there is a error: Uncaught TypeError: Object 47 has no method 'on'

**Update**
Edited according to Felix, and there is no more error. But it seems not to lay out the images as it is supposed to do: re-fit the images in layout.

Help or guide appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$('.grid-tile img').on('load', function() {
```

instead of:

```
$imgs.on('load error', function(){
```

since `var $imgs = $('.grid-tile img').length;` return a string, not a `jQuery` object.

Comment: there is no more error, but still it doesn't lay out images in correct arrangement as freewall pininterest

Comment: Then there's probably something wrong with your CSS, please check if you're missing any file there.

Comment: everything is included. strange. before I commented the lines out, it was working well but because of visibility: hidden, all images disappear. So i had to fiddle code.